# MIDL compiler appending a custom string-valued attribute

Tags: midl

Is it possible to suppress the MIDL compiler from appending a custom atrribute to the resulting interface definition in the resulting COM dll build?
I'm suspecting that the attribute appended by MIDL compiler renders our dll to fail and cause  an error: "Automation server cannot create object", due to its insertion of string-valued attribute. These info are extracted by Oleview.exe's Itypelib viewer.

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: <could not determine filename>
[
   uuid(3F452555-ABB7-402C-BDBA-185B2F71C800),
  version(1.0),
  custom(DE77BA64-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 117441067),   custom(DE77BA63-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 1433773761), custom(DE77BA65-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, "Created by MIDL         version     7.00.0555 at Mon Jun 08 22:29:18 2015
")
```

Here's the definition from the working version of our dll  and is what i am intending to copy while using  Visual Studio 2013 with  MIDL version 8.

```
// Generated .IDL file (by the OLE/COM Object Viewer)
// 
// typelib filename: <could not determine filename>
[
  uuid(3F452555-ABB7-402C-BDBA-185B2F71C800),
  version(1.0),
  custom(DE77BA64-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 117441067),
  custom(DE77BA63-517C-11D1-A2DA-0000F8773CE9, 1433773761)
]
```